# Ocelot Gateway Aggregation: When each API has different Query String parameters

Tags: .net-core, microservices, aggregation, gateway, ocelot

I am working on microservice and I want to aggregate data from multiple Get calls with different Query parameters. e.g

1. /api/Users/Clients?**clientId**=489842&&**isClient**=true
2. /api/Bookings/Booking?**clientId**=489842&**FromDate**=20201106&**ToDate**=20210106
3. /api/Accounts/Salary?**clientId**=489842&**month**=03&**year**=2020

what would be the solution for doing this?
the only solution I found is when all the APIs expecting the single/same query parameter.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot use Aggregation from the Ocelot for this scenario.
But, you can create your own controller directly in ApiGateway and make aggregations by hand.